# Why does Typescript shows event deprecated for Lambda Handler?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to define lambda handler in a typescript environment.

```
const sampleFunc = async (event) => {
  console.log('request:', JSON.stringify(event, undefined, 2));
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
    body: `Hello, CDK! You've hit ${event.path}\n`,
  };
};
exports.handler = sampleFunc(event);
```

For the event it is strikethrough ( couldn't format in questions)  and the compiler say it is deprecated.

deprecation message :

```
'event' is deprecated.ts(6385)
lib.dom.d.ts(17314, 5): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
```

However for the same code when I am not defining function separately it works.

```
    exports.handler = async function (event) {
  console.log('request:', JSON.stringify(event, undefined, 2));
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
    body: `Hello, CDK! You've hit ${event.path}\n`,
  };
};
```

Comment: That means they should no longer be used in new code as they are soon to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is not with the function definition itself but how you export it.

You have to export the *function* not *call* it:

**Wrong:**

```js
exports.handler = sampleFunc(event);
```

**Right:**

```js
exports.handler = sampleFunc;
```

You could also export the function directly:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('request:', JSON.stringify(event, undefined, 2));
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: `Hello, CDK! You've hit ${event.path}\n`,
    };
};
```